# Как вывести в echo текст и значение переменной

Tags: php

Пробовал

```
<?php echo 'Текущий E-mail: <?php echo $emailq["email"]; ?>' ?>
```

Но не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alt

```
Текущий E-mail:  <?php echo $emailq["email"]; ?>
```

alt

```
<?php printf('Текущий E-mail: %s', $emailq["email"]); ?>
```

alt

```
<?php echo 'Текущий E-mail: ', $emailq["email"] ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $value='value';
    echo "text {$value}";

$arr['ind']='val';
echo "{$arr['ind']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "text" . $var;
?>
```

Comment: alt:

    echo "text $array[key] text";

Comment: @Fike ты не пиши такой пример - он сейчас ответит, что не работает ;)